# Creating new data.frame by splitting comma separated entries in old one

Tags: r, string, dataframe, vector

I would like to create a new data-frame with two new columns.
The dataframe would include "extended" `v3` which is derived by breaking down the values separated by comma in `v2` on the left and create two new columns, one with simply corresponding values from `v1` which were in the same column, and second with values from `v1` divided by the number of values that were included and separated by comma in corresponding row in the `df`.
In other words, if like in this example

```
> df[1,]
  v1  v2
1  1 1,3
```

Then the new df would have the following new entries in the first two rows:

```
  v1 v2_split  v3
1  1  1       0.5
2  1  3       0.5
```

Below is a reproducible example:

```
v1 <- c(1,5,3,7,9,3,2,5,NA,7)
v2 <- c("1,3","2","0.05,4,6,7","0",NA,"6","7","10,11","9","0.1")
df <- data.frame(v1,v2)
df$v2 <- as.character(df$v2)
v2_split <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(df$v2,",")))
```

Comment: Not sure how you want cases with multiple rows, like `v1 =` 3, 5, 7 to look like in your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I got the question completely right but seems you want the following:

```
v2_split <- strsplit(df$v2,",")

df <- data.frame(v1 = rep(v1, lengths(v2_split)),
                 v2 = as.numeric(unlist(v2_split)),
                 v3 = rep(v1/lengths(v2_split), lengths(v2_split))
                 )
```

And the result:

```
> df

   v1    v2   v3
1   1  1.00 0.50
2   1  3.00 0.50
3   5  2.00 5.00
4   3  0.05 0.75
5   3  4.00 0.75
6   3  6.00 0.75
7   3  7.00 0.75
8   7  0.00 7.00
9   9    NA 9.00
10  3  6.00 3.00
11  2  7.00 2.00
12  5 10.00 2.50
13  5 11.00 2.50
14 NA  9.00   NA
15  7  0.10 7.00
```